# Monitor a HTTPS connection with URL class (Java)

Tags: java, url, ssl, https, monitoring

I would like to **monitor a simple url**. But when its a https server I get a **handshake exception**. Its possible to verify state of a https url the way browser use to connect? (without having a local certificate). I don't know how browsers do to get content from a https url but I would like to make it the same way. Without need to store a specific certificate for each server. The https being monitored should be anyone.

```
try {
    URL u = new URL(row.getUrl());
    String protocol = u.getProtocol();
    if(protocol.equals("https")) {
        HttpsURLConnection hc = (HttpsURLConnection)u.openConnection();
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + hc.getResponseCode());
        hc.disconnect();
    }
    if(protocol.equals("http")) {
    u.openConnection();
    u.getContent();
    }
    System.out.println("url is up.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    (...)
}
```

Comment: Is the server's certificate trusted? I.e. signed by a CA and not expired? If not then you may have to do some cajoling to get it to work right. Accepting self-signed certificates may require additional work.

Comment: no, it should be any host you like to test availability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't care about the validity of the server's certificate, then you want to set an [`SSLContext`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) that has a [`TrustManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/TrustManager.html) that doesn't check anything. Then you need to use that to set the default [`SSLSocketFactory`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) into the [`HttpsURLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), so that the trust manager is used when you use the [`URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). Here's an example:

```
TrustManager[] trustEverything = new TrustManager[] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
    }
};

SSLContext sslctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslctx.init(null, trustEverything, null);

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslctx.getSocketFactory());
```

A full example using this technique can be found [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=211).

As @erickson points out, this means that you can't tell if you're really talking to the server you're concerned about. An even better solution is to update your Trust store to include the self-signed certificate of the server you're talking to, instead of ignoring all checks.

Comment: I came up to some struggling but found this from your sample: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=211

Now it working. Thanks.

Comment: Good solution, but just remember: you're only checking that "some" server is up; you've lost server authentication so you don't know for sure whether it's yours or a spoof.

Comment: Thanks @Ruben Trancoso, glad I could point you in the right direction. I'll add that link to my answer.

Comment: Excellent point, @erickson. We're throwing away an important feature of SSL/TLS by doing this... I'll add something to my answer to address that.